# Removing the for loops for mean calculation with batch with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

```
B = spec_x.size(0)
H = spec_x.size(1)
T = spec_x.size(2)

# Initialize x tensor with zeros
z = torch.zeros(B, 256, H).to(pitch.device)

# Iterate over each batch element
for b in range(B):
    # Iterate over each pitch index
    for i in range(256):
        # Mask spec_x where pitch equals i
        masked_spec_x = spec_x[b].masked_select(pitch[b] == i)
        
        # Compute mean along the time dimension
        mean_spec_x = torch.mean(masked_spec_x, dim=0)
        
        # Assign the mean to the corresponding position in x
        z[b, i] = mean_spec_x
```

The above code has 2 tensors, spec_x, and pitch. pitch is B T, it's a 2D tensor and it tells us an index from 0 to 255 corresponding to the pitch of the spectrogram at each frame.

The goal is to build tensor z which is B, 256, H, where H is the hidden size of spec_x.

```
z[b][i] = average of spec_x[b] where pitch == i
```

The above code works, but it's very slow because of the loops, I'm just not sure if there's a way to remove the loops using pytorch built ins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I see is to use a reduce function to distribute the values from `spec_x` at indices given by `pitch`. The [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) function seems complex to set up but all you need to do is make sure that

1. All three tensors (`z`, `src`, and `index`) have the same number of dimensions;
2. The indexing tensor (`index`) has values smaller than the dimension size of the output tensor (`z`) at the scattering dimension (`dim`).

To accommodate for the dimension different, we can unsqueeze and expand all three tensors. The output tensor `z` intermediate shape is `(B,C,H,T)`:

```
>>> z = torch.zeros(B,C,H,T)
>>> index = pitch[:,None,None].expand_as(z)
>>> src = spec_x[:,None].expand_as(z)
```

The scattering operation will be applied on `dim=1` (dimension indexed by integers between `[0, 255[`). In pseudo-code, that corresponds to:

```
# z[b][index[b][c][h][t]][h][t] = src[b][c][h][t]
```

The first step is to scatter the values:

```
>>> o = z.scatter(dim=1, index=index, src=src)
```

A trick to get the correct average computed is to apply the same operation but on a tensor of ones of the same shape as `src`:

```
>>> count = z.scatter(dim=1, index=index, src=torch.ones_like(src))
```

Then simply sum `o` and `count` over their last two dimensions and divide `o` by the counts:

```
>>> out = o.sum(dim=(-1,-2)) / count.sum(dim=(-1,-2))
```

You may notice that the output tensor is not of the desired shape, you can fix that by repeating the hidden state dimension since all values are equal row-wise:

```
>>> out[:,:,None].repeat(1,1,H)
```